# Open PDF from terminal using command completion

Tags: terminal, macports

I'm used to the linux way of opening a PDF from the terminal. That is, via e.g. `evince sample.pdf`. Command completion makes this fairly fast. In particular when there are many files with the same name but different endings (like after pdflatex compilations). From macports I have the bash-completion, but it is ineffective for the `open` command in the sense that I have to cycle through all files until I get the PDF one. Is there another way of opening a PDF that allows to employ the bash-completion? Or a way to make `open` ignore certain file types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open` is a generic file-opener-thing so a generic completion for `open` must match anything `open` can open. One workaround is to invent a new command name, `alias` it to `open`, and then specify that the new command should complete PDF files.

```
bash-4.4$ alias viewpdf=open
bash-4.4$ complete -f -X '!*.@(pdf|PDF)' viewpdf
```

You could then use `viewpdf` to tab-complete-open PDF files. However this is rather incomplete as it only matches filenames unqualified with any directory path. With more complexity:

```
alias viewpdf=open
function _viewpdf()
{
   local word=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
   COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f -X "!*.@(pdf|PDF)" -- "${word}"))
}
complete -d -X '.[^./]*' -F _viewpdf viewpdf
```

Which should be saved into [a `bash` rc file](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile).

If you instead use the Z-Shell `zsh` the completion might look like

```
REVERT=$options[COMPLETE_ALIASES]
setopt COMPLETE_ALIASES
alias viewpdf=open
compdef '_files -g "*.(pdf|PDF)"' viewpdf
options[COMPLETE_ALIASES]=$REVERT
unset REVERT
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @thrig. Just to clarify: this works analogue to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/A-Programmable-Completion-Example.html), right? Do I see it correctly, that this does not rely on the macports bash-completion, but merely on the `complete` command.

Comment: yes, but you'll need to ensure you're using a modern version of `bash` and not the old one Apple ships under `/bin`